# Do you need to set maxReceivedMessageSize when using MTOM?

Tags: .net, wcf

I was wondering if setting the maxReceivedMessageSize is necessary when using MTOM or does the MTOM protocol regulate this for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you must configure `maxReceiveMessageSize` and `ReaderQuotas`.